Dynamically Change Input Field Class Based on Validation (Name & Password)
I'm working on a form in CodeIgniter where I want to dynamically change the input field class based on validation status for both the name and password fields. My problem is when I submit a valid name and invalid password, both password and name turned red.
My desired output is if the name is valid it will turn green and password turn red because it's invalid when submitted.
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Here's the relevant code snippet from my view or Github repository:
form.php (VIEW)
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" class=<?php echo (isset($name_valid) && $name_valid === true) ? '"text-green-500"' : '"text-red-500"'; ?>>
<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" class="<?php echo (isset($password_valid) && $password_valid == 'true') ? 'text-green-500' : 'text-red-500'; ?>">

UserController.php (Controller method)
public function create() {
        $this->load->model('UserModel');
        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $validated_result = $this->UserModel->validate_input($data);

        if ($validated_result['name_valid'] === true) {
            $data['name_valid'] = true;
        }
        if ($validated_result['password_valid'] === true) {
            $data['password_valid'] = true;
        }
        $this->load->view('form', $data);

UserModel.php
 public function validate_input($data) {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required|trim|regex_match[/^[^0-9]+$/]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[5]|max_length[100]');

        $result['name_valid'] = $this->form_validation->run(['name' => $data['name']]);
        $result['password_valid'] = $this->form_validation->run(['password' => $data['password']]);

        return $result;
    }


"My desired output is if the name is valid it will turn green and password turn red when submitted"
So validation works just issue is with a front end... Please post frontend code snippet then... My guess is that you use same function for validating both and when calling it and one of them is invalid it returns false and marks both red :)

Yes, that's my guess, too. But I set validation flags based on individual field validation status ( $result['name_valid'] = $this->form_validation->run(['name' => $data['name']]); $result['password_valid'] = $this->form_validation->run(['password' => $data['password']]);). So for example, when name is valid it will return true and if password is invalid it will return false but somehow it return both false.

The frontend is in form.php. If true it should return the inputted data with a green text color.

Like i said you are doing run 2 times and returning result for both of them, your validation logic is not independentbper form field...

You cannot use $this->form_validation->run() with the name and data for a single field like that. The only argument the run method accepts is the name of a group, which refers to a set of validation rules in a config file, which will then be applied to the entire form, not individual fields.
And by calling $this->form_validation->run() twice, it's executing the 2 validation rules you set above for the two fields twice. Both calls will give you the result for the form as a whole, not for the individual fields (so either true if both fields validate or false if one or both fields have errors).
To get the error for an individual field you can use $this->form_validation->error('fieldName'); after calling $this->form_validation->run();, this gives you the error message for the field or an empty string if the field is valid. You can cast this to a boolean value if needed:
public function validate_input($data) {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_data($data);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required|trim|regex_match[/^[^0-9]+$/]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[5]|max_length[100]');

    $this->form_validation->run();

    $result['name_valid'] = !$this->form_validation->error('name');
    $result['password_valid'] = !$this->form_validation->error('password');

    return $result;
}

You can leave out the $data argument and $this->form_validation->set_data($data); if you want to validate data from the $_POST array (which seems to be what you are doing) - the form validation library validates the $_POST data by default if you do not pass any data into it.
And instead of using $this->form_validation->error('fieldName'); to get the error and then pass it into the view, you can also access the errors in the view directly with form_error('fieldName'), like this:
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" class=<?php echo !form_error('name') ? '"text-green-500"' : '"text-red-500"'; ?>>
<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" class="<?php echo !form_error('password') ? 'text-green-500' : 'text-red-500'; ?>">

Hope any of this is helpful!
